# Resizing image discord.py

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, discord.py, gif

I cannot seem to figure out how to resize images and gifs using discord.py

If anyone could tell me how exactly to resize images and gifs using discord.py it would be greatly appreciated as it powers core features of my bot.

Comment: discord.py is not an image manipulation library? Maybe you meant something else with your question?
You can use `pillow` for image manipulation

Comment: I am attempting to use pillow on my discord.py bot to resize and compress images

Comment: Then can you please rephrase your question around Pillow, due to discord.py not actually being whats used. Also, we aren't wizards, can you show us what you've tried so far etc

Answer (score 4):

No there is no such library in discord.py that can resize images and gifs.
Although you can get help from pillow:

1. Download an image from google(ex- wanted template)
2. Now go to your command prompt and type `pip install pillow`
3. Now add this to your code -

```
from PIL, import Image 
from io import BytesIO
```

4. Now this is my code you can set it according to your requirements

```
@client.command()
async def wanted(ctx, user:discord.Member = None):
    if user=None:
        user=ctx.author
    wanted=image.open(wanted.jpg)
    asset= ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = image.open(data)
```

5. Now let's come to your question that is resizing. You can not do it using discord.py but Microsoft paint will help you with this. Open your image (wanted.jpg in my case) with Microsoft paint. Draw a square on the empty area of your template. It will be the place where your images and gifs will appear. Now you will see the size of your square at the bottom of your paint, note it somewhere. In my case, it was 400*600px. Now move your cursor to the top left corner of the square. You will see a graphical reading. In my case, it was 100*200px. Note this reading.
6. Now time to add this thing to your code.

```
pfp=pfp.resize(200,200) #you can resize it to any size you want
wanted.paste(pfp, (100, 200)) # this is my graphical reading
wanted.save(profile.jpg)
await ctx.send(file, discord.File('profile.jpg'))
```

and this is it. I gave you the direction if you are still facing any problems, feel free to comment below, I will try to reply it ; )

Comment: Well, you are saving the resized image into local disk. What if i wanna do it in real time? Like, open the image, resize, and give the resized img to File as input directly?

Comment: You cannot directly send it. When you get the image from discord, it is a coroutine. We then convert it to bytes so we can mess with the image. After making changes with the image, we **have** to save it somewhere or else there is nothing to send. Every thing we do gets stored somewhere. Even the variables you create in python are stored in memory. You cannot send the image directly